# Submit the form as an object

Tags: angular

I'm trying to send an object with data, but in the console it says that all fields are undefined. Can't figure out how to submit the form?

**service:**

```
public counterparties(item: Object) {
  return this.http.post(url, {
    counterparty: item
  })
}
```

**component:**

```
public save() {
  const { data } = this.form.value;
  const counterpartyData = {
    item1: data.inn,
    item2: data.bank,
    item3: data.bik
    }
 }
```

Comment: Have you aver tried to console log data from { data } = this.form.value ? What do you get there ?

Comment: @MissaConstant Yes, I receive just such data. { item1: "123", item2: "321", etc }

Comment: Can you add code for what your form is and also what your full save() function is doing so that we can take a look